# Adding thumbnails to Bootstrap Carousel for WordPress Query

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, wordpress

I have the following code setup to pull sticky posts from WordPress and put them in a Bootstrap Carousel.

How would I go about adding a responsive thumbnail navigation row horizontally that highlights the active thumbnail and limits them to 6 or so?

http://pastebin.com/hmBDmtg2

Comment: "the following code" ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 7
    ));
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
   $i++;
?>
    <div class="item <?php if($i == 1) { echo 'active'; }?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </div>
   </div><!-- item active -->
<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div><!-- carousel-inner -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div><!-- #myCarousel -->
```